# In the Scala^Z3 DSL, how is an uninterpreted function declared?

Tags: scala, dsl, z3

I have a small Scala program that transforms a Scala^Z3 DSL expression into latex for easy reading. But I don't see how to declare an uninterpreted function using the DSL. There are many ways to hack the behavior of a function using other constructs, and it's easy to print a hacked function so it looks like a normal function in latex. But I would rather just declare an uninterpreted function, if that is possible somehow.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve with uninterpreted functions is to use Scala function types in the `Val[_]` type constructor. For instance:

```
import z3.scala._
import z3.scala.dsl._

choose(
  (x : Val[Int], f : Val[Int=>Int]) => x < f(x)
)

> res0: (Int, Int=>Int) = (0,<function1>)
```

The function is then modeled by an actual Scala function:

```
val f = res0._2
f(0)

> 1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the syntax a bit more? I've been searching the scala docs for a way to understand how this works, and have tried several hundred combinations of things, but I can't come up with a way to get a BoolOperand from the construct you suggest. The part I know how to do is `new Eq(function, new IntConstant(3))`. Anything beyond that is a dark and mysterious region of scala and/or Z3... thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of `ValHandler`? It defines a "supporting class" that a type needs in order to be used with `find`, `findAll`, etc. in the DSL. This is an example of the concept of "typeclasses".

Comment: Yes, I tried making a ValHandler for my new function type, but I couldn't work out the syntax properly. When I pass my new BoolOperand to the Z3Context, it aborts the calling method without throwing any exception...! I'm not sure how this is possible in the JVM, though I didn't look at the bytecode. Anyway, I'm simply not able to make this work without a complete example. Do you know where I might find one?